# Redis SADD multiple workers

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, concurrency

I am using Redis server version 7.0.0 with Django-Redis. I have multiple workers in production and plan to use Django Redis's [get_redis_connection](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis#raw-client-access).sadd to add values to a Set() in Redis. When multiple workers do that in Production, will data be lost due to two workers executing simultaneously?

I read that Redis's I/O is single-threaded before version 6.0; since I am using 7.0 (I/O multi-threaded), can concurrency issues/race conditions exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When multiple workers do that in Production, will data be lost due to two workers executing simultaneously?

No.

> since I am using 7.0 (I/O multi-threaded), can concurrency issues/race conditions exist?

No.

Comment: and this approach is Production safe?

Comment: @fiskrisktisk yes